# extracting text inside brackets & text outside with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the text inside the brackets, but also the text outside, until the next opening bracket, but not required.

This is the regex I tried:

```
/\[(?<colors>.+)\](?<text>.+?)(?=\[)/gm
```

And this is the text

```
[F:White,B:Yellow]This is some text[F:Green]more text here
[F:White,B:Yellow]This is a anothr text
```

Without the positive lookahead `(?=\[)` both capture groups have wrong behaviour.

[image: regex101]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `[^][]+` pattern ([negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)) to match 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]`:

```
\[(?<colors>[^][]+)](?<text>[^][]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7uObL3/2). Note that in the demo, I added `\n` to the negated character classes as the test is done on a single multiline string, if you test against multiple separate, standalone strings, you do not need it.

In some regex engines, you have to escape `[` or `]` or both inside a character class, as in Java, Ruby or Swift/Objective-C (Boost library), so use

```
\[(?<colors>[^\]\[]+)](?<text>[^\]\[]+)
```

If `text` group may be empty, replace `(?<text>[^\]\[]+)` with `(?<text>[^\]\[]*)`, `*` will match 0 or more occurrences.